# Issue on Making 100% Sidebar and Container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can you please take a look at [this LINK](http://prowebsolutions.ca/wp-content/themes/ThirdTheme/CDG/index.html) and let me know why I am not able to make a 100% height two column layout?

As you can see I am using

```
html, body { 
  height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid{
  padding:0;
  height:100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
.row-fluid{
  margin-left:0px; 
  background-color:#F5F5F5 !important;
  height:100% !important; 
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
.well.sidebar-nav{
  background-color:#383E4B !important;
  left:0;
  border:none;
  max-width:300px !important;
  margin-left: 0!important;
  height:100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
.span9{
  background-color:#F5F5F5 !important;
  padding-top:50px; 
  margin-top:10px; 
  border:none !important; 
  height:100% !important;  
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
.navbar .avbar-inverse .navbar-fixed-top{
  border:none !important;
}
```

**Update**
And here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/6F7jP/2/)

Comment: man that css looks like it was done by a madman. Ill touch it up for others real quick.

Comment: I would recommend jsfiddling this out with your current css to ensure proper functionality. I believe that the span just fills to the amount of content present in the span. I am not sure if you can force a 100% on the height. Maybe a css wizard is knows how to do this type of magic

Comment: Hi Dan, I update the post with jsfiddle linked

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, styles looks really crazy, you should try use examples on the web how to do [simple two column design](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enGB531GB531&q=two%20column%20css&oq=two%20column%20css&gs_l=serp.3..0l8j0i20j0.1978.2429.0.2596.3.2.0.1.1.0.99.192.2.2.0....0...1c.1.25.serp..0.3.194.R1I856EJ3I8).

Anyway, a simple way to achieve this is to use css pseudo property `:after`

```
.span2:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Also don't forget to add `height: 100%;`

```
.row-fluid .span2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 14.8936%;
}
```

Comment: well, this just a copy from Bootstrap Examples!

Comment: oh ok, I have never used them and as I see for a good reason. Nonetheless even that kind of css could be managed to achieve what you need. Hopefully my answer will help you do just that!